# Invalid user error using chown

Tags: 14.04, permissions, users, home-directory, cluster

I am running into an issue where when I type in sudo chown, I am recieving an invalid user error.

I created a user called clusterUser using the GUI. In the root directory of the computer (/), I created a folder called clusterFiles. I would like to change the home directory of clusterUser to be clusterFiles. I am using this set of commands to change the home directory:

```
sudo chown clusterUser /clusterFiles
sudo usermod -d /clusterFiles clusterUser
```

However, when I run the command `sudo chown clusterUser /clusterFiles`, I get the error invalid user clusterUser.

I know that I have created it becuase I logged into it. Is there something wrong with how I formatted the command?

Edit:

The output of `getent passwd | grep 'cluster'` yeilds:

```
rgcluster2blade1:x:1000:1000:RGcluster2Blade1,,,:/home/rgcluster2blade1:/bin/bas‌​h
clusteruser:x:1002:1002:clusterUser,,,:/home/clusteruser:/bin/bash
```

Comment: What is the output of `getent passwd | grep 'cluster'`

Comment: @steeldriver Sorry for the late reply. the output is as follows: rgcluster2blade1:x:1000:1000:RGcluster2Blade1,,,:/home/rgcluster2blade1:/bin/bash.   And the 2nd line: clusteruser:x:1002:1002:clusterUser,,,:/home/clusteruser:/bin/bash

Comment: Would be much easier to decode if you [edit] it into your Q but it looks to me like you're confusing the GECOS 'full name' (`clusterUser` - mixed case) with the actual Unix username `clusteruser` (all lower case)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for the recommendation, I updated my post. So the chown command is looking for the unix username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your `passwd` file, the username is `clusteruser` with a real name of `clusterUser` (`clusteruser:...:clusterUser...`). `chown` cares only about the username, which has no capital letters.

Use `chown clusteruser`.